# Neural networks - why is loss always 0.0 and accuracy 1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to train my neural network with 10 epochs. But my attempts are unsuccessful. I don't get it why am I always getting something like this:

```
 35/300 [==>...........................] - ETA: 1:09 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
 36/300 [==>...........................] - ETA: 1:09 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
 37/300 [==>...........................] - ETA: 1:08 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

Here are my batch size and image width/height and whole feeding proccess:

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 150
img_width = 150

    dataset_url = "http://cnrpark.it/dataset/CNR-EXT-Patches-150x150.zip"
    print(dataset_url)
    data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=dataset_url,
                                       fname='CNR-EXT-Patches-150x150',
                                       untar=True)
                
    train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
      data_dir,
      validation_split=0.2,
      subset="training",
      seed=123,
      image_size=(img_height, img_width),
      batch_size=batch_size)
    num_classes = 1
    
    val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
      data_dir,
      validation_split=0.2,
      subset="validation",
      seed=123,
      image_size=(img_height, img_width),
      batch_size=batch_size)
    
    
    class_names = train_ds.class_names
    print(class_names)
    
    
    for image_batch, labels_batch in train_ds:
      print(image_batch.shape)
      print(labels_batch.shape)
      break
    
    normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
    
    normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
    image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
    first_image = image_batch[0]
    print(np.min(first_image), np.max(first_image))
    
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
    ])
    
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    
    train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    
    model.compile(
      optimizer='adam',
      loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
      metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    model.fit(
      train_ds,
      validation_data=val_ds,
      epochs=10
    )
```

From np.min and np.max I'm getting these values: `0.08627451 0.5568628` so this obviously wouldn't be the case. What should be wrong in my attempt?

EDIT, my epoch looks like this now:

```
  5/300 [..............................] - ETA: 1:12 - loss: 0.1564 - accuracy: 0.9750
  6/300 [..............................] - ETA: 1:15 - loss: 0.1311 - accuracy: 0.8333
  7/300 [..............................] - ETA: 1:13 - loss: 0.1124 - accuracy: 0.7143
  8/300 [..............................] - ETA: 1:13 - loss: 0.0984 - accuracy: 0.6250
  9/300 [..............................] - ETA: 1:12 - loss: 0.0874 - accuracy: 0.5556
```

And a little later:

```
 51/300 [====>.........................] - ETA: 1:04 - loss: 0.0154 - accuracy: 0.0980
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set `num_classes = 1`, although your dataset has two [classes](http://cnrpark.it/):

> LABEL is 0 for free, 1 for busy.

So, if you want to use `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`, try:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
```

You could also consider using `binary_crossentropy` if you only have two classes. You would have to change your loss function and output layer to:

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
```

Comment: This helps so much! I didn't use labels as a class this was my fault.

Comment: Could you add some example of using ```binary_crossentropy ```  in my case?

Comment: Just change your loss function to `loss=tf.keras.losses. BinaryCrossentropy()` and the last layer as in my answer.

Comment: Just did that, now my accuracy is falling below 0.1, why is that happening?

Comment: Hard to say without further details

Comment: I changed in my question the line of code to be identical to what I'm using now

Comment: Also updated how epoch looks like

Comment: Well obviously :D, .. Delete the last layer...you only need `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")` **not** `tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)`

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm still beginner in neural networks :D... Is it okay for accuracy to be > ```0.99```?

Answer (score 1):

You need the following:

```
num_classes = 2
tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax)
```

I can see a  `normalization_layer`, looks like you are rescaling twice.